# renaming filenames to integer sequence in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-rename

I need to rename filenames in a folder containing many text files.
The renaming should follow the sequence of numbers for every file.
It should be like as follows:

```
***given files***     ***renamed files***
abc.txt              1.txt
def.txt              2.txt
rsd.txt              3.txt
ijb.txt              4.txt
```

the above files are in a folder named `data`

my code is like this

```
import glob 
import os
file=sorted(glob.glob("/home/prasanth/Desktop/project/prgms/dt/details/*.txt"))
fp=[]
for b in file:
    fp.append(b)
i=1
for f in fp:
    n=f.replace('.html','')
    n=n.replace('.htm','')
    m=n.replace(n,str(i)+'.txt')
    i=i+1
    os.rename(f,m)
```

my problem is the files after renaming are moving into the folder where the python code is written.but i need the renamed files in the same folder in which they are present before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great, so what have you tried?

As a starting point, have a look at the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#module-os)-module, especially [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) and [`os.rename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename).

EDIT:

Your files are moved, because you replace the whole path with the number with `m=n.replace(n,str(i)+'.txt')`. This renames `subfolder\textfile.txt` to be renamed to `1.txt`, which moves the file to the current directory as a side effect.

Also I am not sure what you try to achieve with the htm(l)-replaces, since afterwards you replace everything with your number.

Additionally, you don't need to build a copy of the list of txt-files and afterwards iterate over it, you can do it directly on the original file list.

So this could probably work for you:

```
import glob
import os

filelist=sorted(glob.glob("/home/prasanth/Desktop/project/prgms/dt/details/*.txt"))
i=1

for oldname in filelist:
    # ignore directories
    if os.path.isfile(oldname):
        # keep original path
        basepath=os.path.split(oldname)[0]
        newname=os.path.join(basepath, "{}.txt".format(str(i)))
        i=i+1
        print("Renaming {} to {}".format(oldname, newname))
        os.rename(oldname, newname)
```

Side note: the rename will fail when a file with the new file name already exists. You should probably handle that with `try ... except`.

Comment: i had tried os.rename()  and every other code but not got exact solution

Comment: So show what you have tried and the errors you encountered. Otherwise it is difficult to help you with your specific problem.

Comment: Please add your code to your original question, so it is formatted nicely. On a first glance, your code "works" (as in: it is renaming text files) - please also add a description, what it should do and what it does instead. Maybe have another look at [ask].

Comment: This helps me to continue my code to further level..Thanks for the code